# Describe geometrically what the function $f(z)=z^k$ for $k$ some positive integer does to the points on a line through the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe geometrically what the function $f(z)=z^k$ for $k$ some positive integer does to the points on a line through the origin or to the points on a circle with center at the origin.

We are able to write any complex number in terms of e to some power, and $z^k$ will be the roots of unity of $z$. So what I am thinking is that the points through the origin or to the points on a circle will describe the radius?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line through the origin is given by $r e^{i\theta}$ for $r$ an arbitrary real and $\theta$ fixed. So the $k$th powers are $r^k e^{ik\theta}$ for $r$ real. Something here is different depending as $k$ is even or odd: do you see it? A circle is $re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta$ varying over $\mathbf{R}$ and $r$ fixed. Try the same trick I used for the line and see if you can figure out what happens.

Comment: Would the second case bring us with an extra $e^a$ where $a$ is an artibrary constant?

Comment: No, you get $r^ke^{ik\theta}$ with $\theta$ still varying.